# Anaconda (Python) not loading from /etc/environment in Ubuntu 15

Tags: python, path, environment-variables, anaconda

I previously installed Anaconda on a Ubuntu 15 machine, and I added the path to `/etc/environment` so that it would be the standard python environment for all users on the machine.

This is my `/etc/environment` file:

```
PATH="/usr/local/bin/anaconda2/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin/SeqPrep:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games"
export PATH
```

This worked fine for several weeks and launched the Anaconda shell when I typed `python` in my terminal.

Now, I try `which python` and I get the standard install, `/usr/bin/python`.

Here is `/etc/profile`: it doesn't contain anything Python-related.

```
PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/bin/mira_4.0.2_linux-gnu_x86_64_static/bin
PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/bin/SOAPec_src_v2.03/bin
PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/bin/SOAPdenovo2-bin-LINUX-generic-r240
PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/bin/samtools-1.3/bin
PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/bin/seqtk
PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/bin/bwa-0.7.13
export PATH
```

My `~/.bash_profile` doesn't contain anything related to `$PATH`. I have looked at other questions on Stack Overflow and they mostly pertain to changing a single user's python environment, not the environment for the whole system.

I am not sure about using `PYTHONPATH`, but I have read several posts that it is best to not edit this variable, so avoiding it seems ideal.

EDIT: I fixed this problem by reinstalling the anaconda distribution. Perhaps it had something to do with the file permissions? Now if I edit the PATH variable from `/etc/profile`, `/etc/environment`, or `~/.bash_profile`, the `which python` command accurately reflects what I set.